# Profile a .net core application on mac?

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core, profiling, macos-sierra

I can launch an application like:

```
dotnet myapp.dll
```

But how can I perform time or memory profiling on it?  In visual studio for Mac community edition, no "profile" option shows up under the run menu (it requires enterprise).

I am essentially looking for the equivalent of `mono --profile=log` in .net core 2.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Profiler API is already implemented in .NET Core runtime and available on all major platforms: Windows, Linux, macOS. However, it was thoroughly tested only on Windows and Linux. Devs recommend to profile on macOS with grain of salt and set up some verification tests.

Currently Microsoft offers only Xamarin profiler for macOS. I would evaluate Visual Studio Enterprise for macOS - it is available for 30 day free trial.

Another approach is to use existing basic implementation of .NET Core Profiling API sample in [Microsoft Clr Samples repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/clr-samples/tree/master/ProfilingAPI/ReJITEnterLeaveHooks) - 
`ProfilingAPI - ReJITEnterLeaveHooks` and if needed add some missing functionality. For additional details see CoreCLR GitHub repo issue #14786 [How To Build My Own .Net Core Profiler](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/14786)

Otherwise I am not aware of any other tested and production ready macOS .NET Core profilers.

Comment: Thanks, I wound up taking that approach to write a custom profiler as described here: http://evolvedmicrobe.com/blogs/?p=398

Comment: Seems to be sad state of affairs on macOS tooling right now

Comment: It sounds like dotTrace is currently in some form of beta testing to be able to do profiling on mac (might require other tooling along with it)